# jQuery hide element after append using jquery.validate

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having trouble hiding an element after appending it to a div. I have tried everything and looked all over for an answer. I spent almost the whole day on it.

So I use jquery.validate.js to make a custom error code

```
email: '<img id="img1" class="RCB" src="images/closeButton.png" /><h3>Incorrect Email</h3><p>Please enter a valid email address</p>'
```

which is then appended to my far right div #rightBar

```
errorClass: "rightNotification",
errorElement: "div",

errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
  error.appendTo("#rightBar");
},
```

and then in a seperate js file I try to fade() it when the close button at the top is clicked

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".RCB").live("click", function() {
    $('.rightNotification').hide();
  });
});
```

I have also tried

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".RCB").click(function() {
    $('.rightNotification').hide();
  });
});
```

and a number of other solutions. I basically want the right close button (RCB) to close the entire notification. I can't really think of anything I haven't tried but I'm hoping you can think of something.

Cheers,
Matt

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: have you tried with  `$(".RCB").on("click", function() {`?

Comment: @SumanBogati That's the same as `$(".RCB").click(function(){`

Comment: I tried both but on Document click only works

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use [event delegation](https://api.jquery.com/on/) as it is added dynamically - [`live()`](https://api.jquery.com/live/) was deprecated in version 1.7 and removed in version 1.9:

```
$(document).on("click", ".RCB", function() {
   $('.rightNotification').hide();
});
```

Substitute `document` for a closer container element if possible (for added efficiency).